# Escolher a ordem em que os itens são listados no Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli, order-by, order

Tenho uma tabela com três tipos de ordem, `ordem1`, `ordem2` e `ordem_especial` . Como posso listar os itens nessa ordem:

EXEMPLO:

```
ordem2
ordem_especial
ordem1
```

Tentei sem sucesso algo como :

**SELECT REAL DA APLICAÇÃO**

**EDIT: RESOLVIDO  COM O CÓDIGO ABAIXO**

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM  `IMAGEMCONTROLE`
INNER JOIN  `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL` ON  `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`PRODUTO_PROPOSTA` =  `IMAGEMCONTROLE`.`IMAGEMCONTROLE_PRODUTO`
INNER JOIN  `IMAGEMCONTROLESITE` ON  `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`PRODUTO_PROPOSTA` =  `IMAGEMCONTROLESITE`.`IMAGEMCONTROLE_PRODUTO`
WHERE `IMAGEMCONTROLE`.`IMAGEMCONTROLE_LINHA` > 0 
ORDER BY 
       (
            CASE 
                WHEN   `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`ESPECIAL` ='1' THEN 0 
                WHEN   `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`ESPECIAL` ='2' THEN 1
                WHEN   `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`ESPECIAL` ='3' THEN 2 
                WHEN   `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`ESPECIAL` ='4' THEN 3 
                WHEN   `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`ESPECIAL` ='5' THEN 4 
                WHEN   `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`ORDEM_LANCAMENTO` THEN 5 
                WHEN   `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`ORDEM_PROPOSTA` THEN 6
            END
        ) , 
        `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`ORDEM_PROPOSTA`,
        `PRODUTOS_PROPOSTA_LOCAL`.`ORDEM_LANCAMENTO`
";
```

Preciso listar a IMAGEMCONTROLE_MARCA na ordem acima (Primeiro a marca 19, depois a 23 e assim por diante), depois ORDEM_LANCAMENTO e depois ORDEM_PROPOSTA.

**RESOLVIDO**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendendo que:

```
ordem2
ordem_especial
ordem1
```

sejam o conteúdo de um determinado campo, você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
SELECT ..., (CASE WHEN campo='ordem2' THEN 1 
                  WHEN campo='ordem_especial' THEN 2 
                  WHEN campo='ordem1' THEN 3 
                  ELSE 0
              END) AS n
...
ORDER BY n;
```

Você também pode colocar a expressão CASE diretamente na cláusula ORDER BY.

====================

Não entendi não só sua cláusula CASE quanto estes ASC entremeados na cláusula, me parecem sintaticamente inválidos.

Você tem certeza de que INNER JOIN entre as tabelas é o que realmente deseja?

Defina melhor o que deseja fazer pois, creio, entendi errado seu problema.

Comment: Eu não consegui implementar o CASE se poder ajudar editei a pergunta com o código real.

Comment: Consegui isso resolveu obrigado. Editei o código com a solução.

Answer (score -1):

De acordo com o [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) seria isso mesmo:

```
SELECT column1, column2,...
FROM tbl
ORDER BY column1 [ASC|DESC], column2 [ASC|DESC],...
```

Está dando algum erro? Pode postar mais alguma informação para ajudar a resolver seu problema?

Comment: Não da erro, apenas inverte a listagem e caso eu coloque DESC acerta a ordem da lista porém os itens listados ficam descendentes e preciso ascendente, já vou testar isso te aviso mais infos !

Comment: Não funciona, isso é só um exemplo indicando que pode usar ASC ou DESC apenas.